# Use included javascript from external page

Tags: jquery, android

What I am trying to do, is display an external page, change the css, and display it to the user, with Jquery/javascript+phonegap. However, if the external page has `script` tags, which include `.js` files, then they are excluded, because, I need to modify and save the html locally, then display it again.

Is there a way or is it even possible to include the referenced `.js` files in the saved external html? I know there are reasons for not allowing to save those files locally, but I only need to use them, not read the contents. I know I can modify the `head` element to include 'public' .js files, such as jquery, but how about 'private' .js files?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery get() method is useful here.  With no argument, it returns all matches in an array.  Testing on the W3Schools site seems to reveal this behavior, and, jQuery being a library, I would expect this is not browser dependent.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/misc_get.asp

You could use

```
$("script").get()
```

to find all script tags.  You could even use

```
$("script").get().filter(function(x){return x.src})
  .map(function(x){return x.src}
```

Even better is

```
$("script[src]").get().map(function(x){return x.href})
```

jQuery is a good example of language extension.

Comment: This is a good example, but doesn't quite answer the question of whether it is possible to use javascript as defined in a file on the server, e. g. <script type="text/javascript" src="jss/pagespecific.js"></script>

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to convert the <script type="text/javascript src="code.js"></script> into <script type="text/javascript">/*code*/</script>.  You probably want to do it on the server side.  The solution depends on the technology you are using.  For instance, with PHP, you could do this with cURL or with sockets.  The same-origin policy puts obstacles in the way of doing it on the client.